# What is the meaning of the QUEUE in arptables

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, arp, arptables

I use the nfqueue target of iptables in order to get packet to the nfqueue and do some business rules on them.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

I need to do the same on arp reply and i see that there is QUEUE target in the arptables:

```
arptables -A INPUT -j QUEUE
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out if the queue here is the same as the iptables nfqueue and if not how can i read from it.

I just looking for a way to be called when i get an ARP reply for a given IP.
Using libpcap is in lowest priority , because with libpcap i will need to run on all packets.